# How do I get three finger gestures working again in Twitter for Mac after installing Lion?

Tags: macos, trackpad, multi-touch, twitter

After installing Lion, three finger gestures no longer work in the Twitter for Mac app.  (I've gotten used to swiping left with three fingers to go "back" after—for example—clicking on a person's avatar to see their timeline.)  In the Trackpad System Preferences panel I've disabled three finger drag, and changed "Swipe between full-screen apps", "Mission Control" and "App Exposé" to four fingers to try to eliminate conflicts.  But the three finger swipe still doesn't work in Twitter.

Has anyone been able to re-enable three finger gestures in Twitter for Mac?  How did you do it?

Comment: Have you ever considered downloading Magic Prefs it goes you more touch functionality with your magic mouse/trackpad.

Comment: I'm using BetterTouchTool.  Would it be a mistake to assume they're about the same?

Comment: I used BetterTouchTool to make "Swipe left with three fingers" work in Twitter for Mac, until tbandes's answer helped me get it working without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This annoyed me too, and it doesn't seem the solution is entirely satisfying — we'll just have to hope that Twitter for Mac gets updated soon to be better compatible with Lion.

If you have "Swipe between pages" set to "Swipe left or right with three fingers" or "Swipe with two or three fingers", then left/right three-finger swipe gestures will work in Twitter.

If you have Mission Control & App Exposé set to "Swipe up/down with three fingers", then you can hold <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> to use up/down three-finger swipe gestures with Twitter. (I'm not sure why, but if you have these set to 4-finger swipes, it doesn't seem 3-finger swipes work at all in Twitter.)

[image]

Comment: Left three-finger swipes work in Twitter now that I set "Swipe between pages" to to three fingers.

Comment: But holding Option and three-finger up & down gestures don't work in Twitter after setting Mission Control & App Exposé to four fingers.

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my answer :)

Comment: I'm confused by your last paragraph.  'If you have Mission Control & App Exposé set to "Swipe up/down with four fingers", then you can hold Option to use up/down three-finger swipe gestures with Twitter' makes it sound like this should work.  I assumed "(I'm not sure why, but if you have these set to 4-finger swipes, it doesn't seem 3-finger swipes work at all in Twitter.)" meant that it only works with the Option key held down.

Comment: Aha! Good catch; I meant "Swipe up/down with three fingers". Answer fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Holding the option key and swiping up/down with 4 fingers does the same thing as swiping up/down with 3 fingers did in Snow Leopard. Try it in both Twitter for Mac and Firefox and you'll see.