# How to fix “swipe up” and “swipe down” gestures in Reeder after installing Lion?

Tags: macos, applications, multi-touch

After upgrading to Lion, [Reeder](http://reederapp.com/) swipe up and swipe down gestures stopped working.

[image: Reeder swipe up and swipe down gestures in Lion]

How do I fix them?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is a [known issue](http://reederapp.com/mac/help) and has been fixed in recent versions.

However, it is not specific to Reeder and [seems to also affect Twitter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20938/how-do-i-get-three-finger-gestures-working-again-in-twitter-for-mac-after-install/20980#20980) and other apps.

To work around it, hold <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> and swipe **using the same count of fingers** that you have set for Mission Control in **Trackpad** preference pane:

[image: Swipe up with three fingers]

Comment: Thanks! This was a great workaround which also works in Chrome to trigger Chrome's exposé.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this (temporarily), but there's some plist hacking involved. I read on [reeder's twitter feed](https://twitter.com/reederapp/status/94122392858800128) about a solution to this problem.

> “@jagreenwood: @reederapp i got them working like this tumblr.com/xic3melm6o swipeWithEvent isn't called otherwise”
>   Great, thanks!

The solution described at the [linked address](http://jagreenwood.com/post/7885126032/howto-bring-back-vertical-swiping-in-lion) explains how to fix this problem in a couple of steps:

1. I set up the trackpad properties in Preferences like this:
   [image]
2. open up `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist` in your favorite editor
3. make set the value of key `TrackpadThreeFingerVertSwipeGesture` to 1
4. Restart your computer as this setting otherwise isn't used.

It's a bit hackish, but works pretty fine for me. The author of the post has also a [different solution](http://jagreenwood.com/post/7927447358/the-real-solution-to-bring-back-swiping-to-lion), but I don't really like that there's the option key involved.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately to no avail.