# Chrome Exposé in OS X Lion not working

Tags: macos, google-chrome

In Snow Leopard, Chrome had a feature that is like Exposé, but for the tabs.

The gesture to trigger it was a 3 finger swipe down.

And in Lion it just stopped to work.

Does anyone knows how to enable it in Lion?

Comment: the same you enable all the vertical gestures:  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21413/how-to-fix-swipe-up-and-swipe-down-gestures-in-reeder-after-installing-lion

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to URL `chrome:flags`.
2. Enable [Tab Overview](http://osxdaily.com/2011/03/04/activate-tab-overview-in-chrome-to-get-expose-for-the-web/).
3. Restart Google Chrome.

Please note that this is an experimental feature.